# index.ts:269 Uncaught (in promise) Error: call revert exception while trying to

Tags: solidity, hardhat

index.ts:269 Uncaught (in promise) Error: call revert exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="display(address)", data="0x", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.7.0)
at Logger.makeError (index.ts:269:1)
at Logger.throwError (index.ts:281:1)
at Interface.decodeFunctionResult (interface.ts:427:1)
at Contract. (index.ts:400:1)
at Generator.next ()
at fulfilled (index.ts:1:1)

my contract is
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

```
pragma solidity >= 0.5.0 < 0.9.0;
contract Upload{
    struct Access{
        address user;
        bool access;

    }
    mapping (address=>string[])value;
    mapping (address=>Access[])accessList;
    mapping (address=>mapping (address=>bool))ownership;//2d
    mapping (address=>mapping (address=>bool))previousData;//to check previous state
    function add(address _user,string memory url) external {
        value[_user].push(url);

    }
       function allow(address user) external {//def
      ownership[msg.sender][user]=true; 
      if(previousData[msg.sender][user]){
         for(uint i=0;i<accessList[msg.sender].length;i++){
             if(accessList[msg.sender][i].user==user){
                  accessList[msg.sender][i].access=true; 
             }
         }
      }else{
          accessList[msg.sender].push(Access(user,true));  
          previousData[msg.sender][user]=true;  
      }
    
  }
      function disallow(address user) external{
          ownership[msg.sender][user]=false;
          for(uint i=0;i<accessList[msg.sender].length;i++)
          {
              if(accessList[msg.sender][i].user==user){
                  accessList[msg.sender][i].access=false;

              }

          }
      }
      function display(address _user) external view returns(string[] memory)
      {
          require( _user==msg.sender  || ownership[_user][msg.sender ],"no acces please");
          return value[_user];

      }
   function shareAccess() public view returns(Access[] memory){
      return accessList[msg.sender];
  }
}
```

and this is how i calls

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function Display({ contract, account }) {
  const [address, setAddress] = useState("");

  const get = async () => {
    // Use the address state variable here
    const addr = address;
    if(addr)
    {
      console.log(addr)
      const datarr = await contract.display(addr);
      console.log(datarr);
      
       
    }else{
alert("please add adress")
    }
   
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>iMAGE DISPLAY</div>
      <input
        className=""
        placeholder="address"
        type="text"
        value={address}
        onChange={(e) => setAddress(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={get}>GET PICTURES</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

i deployed on hardhat localhost.